# Equivalent of sh "set -e" and "set +b" in Python

Tags: python

What is the equivalent of unix shell set -e (Exit if a command exits with a non-zero) and set +e in Python?

Comment: I don't think this is a correct question. There are no "commands" in Python, you only call functions. Although you can execute shell commands via `os.system`. I guess `if os.system(cmd) != 0: sys.exit(1)` should do the trick.

Comment: Python handles exceptions very differently from a shell language. There are no exit codes. Instead python makes heavy use of exception handling.  
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: If something raises an exception and nothing catches it, the script will end. So it's like `set -e` is always in place.